# sonar 5.1.1 analysis results for different branches giving timeouts with mysql db

Tags: sonarqube5.1

We are using `Sonarqube 5.1.1` with a MySQL database. We are facing timeout issues with the database. We ran the MySQL tuning primer script and made some changes to the InnoDB timeout (increased it in `/etc/my.cnf`), but it made no difference. One of the suggestions from mysl tuner output is :

> "of 7943 temp tables, 40% were created on disk"
>   Note: BLOB and TEXT columns are not allowed in memory tables.

Are there any suggestions for dealing with Sonar analysis results for a bunch of different branches?

Perhaps using Postgres instead of MySQL? 
We get errors as shown below:

> Failed to process analysis report 8 of project "X"
>   org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>
> #### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException:
>
> org.sonar.core.issue.db.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed.
>   Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction
>
> #### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.core.issue.db.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed.
>
> Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction